# How to create a keygen

Tags: password-cracking

I have a list with approx 500 serial numbers (each one with 10 digits) and all the 500 passcodes generated for those serials (also with 10 digits, but alphanumeric).

Is possible to discover the logic of those passcodes and create a keygen?

Comment: Unfortunately, this depends _entirely_ on the precise technique the target program uses to verify serials. Without knowing a lot more information, no one could possibly answer this question.